# SQL / MYSQL: Two statements in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

`film_actor`, like this:

```
╔═════════╦══════╗
║ film_id ║ Task ║
╠═════════╬══════╣
║    1    ║ 162  ║
║    1    ║ 15   ║
║    1    ║ 20   ║
║    2    ║ 162  ║
║    2    ║ 12   ║
╚═════════╩══════╝
```

than the following query:

```
SELECT film_id
FROM film_actor
WHERE actor_id LIKE '162'
```

the result:

```
1
2
```

the next query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor_id
FROM film_actor
WHERE film_id LIKE 'results from the query above'
```

the result should look like this:

```
15
20
12
```

How can I put together this two queries?
The result of the first one should not be display, its just needed for the secound and final query.

Comment: [nested queries in SQL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm)

Comment: There's no actor_id here

Answer (score 4):

Use `IN` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor_id
FROM film_actor
WHERE film_id in(SELECT film_id
                 FROM film_actor
                 WHERE actor_id LIKE '162')
```

Or with `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f2.actor_id
FROM film_actor f1
JOIN film_actor f2 ON f1.film_id = f2.film_id
WHERE f1.actor_id LIKE '162'
```

Comment: Don't bother with the first solution

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor_id
FROM film_actor
WHERE film_id IN
(
    SELECT film_id
    FROM film_actor
    WHERE actor_id LIKE '162'
)
```

Comment: This seems like overkill for such a trivial problem

Comment: @Strawberry.  Thanks for the feedback.  Giorgi thought of doing the `JOIN` first, so I won't update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thats it

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor_id
FROM film_actor
WHERE film_id in (
  SELECT film_id
  FROM film_actor
  WHERE actor_id LIKE '162'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is [subquery](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php). Yours should looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor_id FROM film_actor WHERE film_id in
(SELECT film_id FROM film_actor WHERE actor_id LIKE '162)
```